# How can i pass data from my Ajax function to a HTML model in a partial view?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I want to use an Ajax function to change the HTML model in a partial view. The function in the MVC controller returns the correct value (List). But how can i pass this data (result) from the Ajax function to a partial view (_locationListPartial) ? This is what I have so far.

**Ajax function**

```
function PassLocationList(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/GetLocations',
        data: { 'id': id },
        success: function (result) {

        *** WHAT CODE DO I NEED HERE (Passing to partial view) ***

        }
    });
}
```

**_locationListPartial**

```
<div class="sidebar_list">

        *** WHAT CODE DO I NEED HERE (@Model list)? ***

        @if (list == null || list.Count() == 0)
        {
            <div>Geen items gevonden!</div>
        }
        else
        {
            @foreach (var item in list)
            {
                <partial name="../Shared/_LocationItemPartial.cshtml" model="@item" />
            }
        }
    </div>
```

**Controller function**

```
[HttpPost]
    public List<Location> GetLocations(int id)
    {
        List<Location> LocationList = _context.Locations.Where(p => p.CategoryId.Equals(id)).ToList();
        return LocationList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you change your controller action to return `_locationListPartial` partial view?  Then you can just use `$(".sidebar_list").html(result)`

Comment: @freedomn-m what code do I need to add in the partial view above the if statement to achieve the data from the Ajax function?

Comment: Change your controller to `return PartialView("_locationListPartial", LocationList)` then in your partial: at the top: `@model List<Location>` then your for loop `@foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: But that's not "passing the *data* from ajax 'to the partial view'" - that's generating a partial view from the Model and is a core concept of [asp.net-mvc]

Comment: @freedomn-m Every time a button is pressed. A new list needs to be returned that changes the model. Sadly with this code it did not work.

Comment: Everytime *what* button is pressed?  There's no button in your code.  You don't even say how `PassLocationList` is called.  Perhaps you could include all the information in your question?

Comment: You have two choices: return html or return data and build the html using javascript.  As you're using MVC, it makes sense to have MVC build the HTML for you, so return a partial view html.